# Does Datamapper support 'On Duplicate Key Update' or other techniques for upserts?

Tags: mysql, ruby, datamapper

I'm loading a ton of records into a MySQL database using Ruby and Datamapper. These records are mostly inserts but there are a fair number of updates. I basically want to 'upsert' all the columns for these records in the database. The only options I can find are:

1) Query for a record. If it exists, update it. If not, create a record. (Always one extra query)
2) Try to create a new record. Catch duplicate key errors. Query for the existing record. Update those records. (When there is an update, 2 extra queries)

I'd like to utilize MySQL's `On Duplicate Key Update` because it seems much more efficient. Is there a way to do this in Datamapper? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `first_or_create` for this.  From the [docs](http://datamapper.org/docs/create_and_destroy.html):

```
zoo = Zoo.first_or_create(:name => 'The Glue Factory')
```

I didn't get any matches by grepping for `On Duplicate Key Update` in the [`do/do_mysql`](https://github.com/datamapper/do/tree/master/do_mysql) or [`dm-mysql-adapter`](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-mysql-adapter) source, so it may not support it.  If the efficiency is that important to require this feature you may need to resort to plain SQL.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't find any trace of it either. I might have to go mysql2 for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a supported feature out of the box, but if you are doing a mass insert, do it within a transaction and that will be more efficient even with the extra query. And use `first_or_new` so you don't do multiple inserts on the new records.

```ruby
DataMapper.respository.transaction.commit do
  Zoo.raise_on_save_failure = true
  bunch_of_updates.each do |key, new_attributes|
    zoo = Zoo.first_or_new(the_key: key)
    zoo.attributes = new_attributes
    zoo.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Cool. I'll remember that trick for next time. Unfortunately I can't que my updates like that. I'm processing xml records and there is too much data to keep in memory before running the insert. It looks like I'll have to use mysql2 (production) and sqlite3 (testing) to 'upsert'.

Comment: Gotcha. You can do it with the adapter directly from DataMapper like `DataMapper.repository.adapter.execute("some sql")`. Or you can probably just keep the queries from datamapper in memory and stream the xml, then run the queries like `DataMapper.repository.adapter.create(query)`.